# How to make date-like URL when showing records in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I get my records to be accessed in the following manner

[image]

instead of typical  `blog/:id` fashion?

Comment: did you try `friendly-id` gem? https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569876/rails-3-2-friendly-url-routing-by-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `friendly-id` gem. More info about it in [GitHub](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

Tutorial in railscasts:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast